# Print to PDF not working on Linux Headless chrome browser for seleminum on python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have setup chrome driver and chrome browser and able to execute code successfully as well but PDF is not getting generating. Its workin on Windows for me.
Here is my code.
Linux: Redhat
Chrome Browser: Version 80.0.3987
Chrome driver

I might need to use some extra arguments for linux:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
settings = {
       "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2
    }
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
    "savefile.default_directory": "/users",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.safebrowsing.enabled": True}


chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options, service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/users/slack/compliance/chromedriver.log'])
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com/')
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")

driver.execute_script('window.print();')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```